# Как приостановить все потоки приложения, кроме выполняющегося

Tags: delphi

Приостановить из выполняющегося потока. Как? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
procedure threadslist(h: integer; onoff: boolean);
var
  ThreadSnapshotHandle: THandle;
  ThreadFound: Boolean;
  ThreadEntry: tagTHREADENTRY32;
  ProcessID, ThreadID: Cardinal;
begin
  ProcessID := GetCurrentProcessId;
  ThreadID := GetCurrentThreadId;
  ThreadSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
  try
    ThreadEntry.dwSize := SizeOf(ThreadEntry);
    ThreadFound := Thread32First(ThreadSnapshotHandle, ThreadEntry);
    if ThreadFound then
    repeat
      if ThreadEntry.th32OwnerProcessID = ProcessID then
      begin

      if ((ThreadEntry.th32ThreadID<>ThreadID) and (ThreadEntry.th32ThreadID<>h)) then
      begin
      if onoff=true then SuspendThread(OpenThread($0002,false,ThreadEntry.th32ThreadID));
      if onoff=false then ResumeThread(OpenThread($0002,false,ThreadEntry.th32ThreadID));
      end;

      end;
    until not Thread32Next(ThreadSnapshotHandle, ThreadEntry);
  finally
    CloseHandle(ThreadSnapshotHandle);
  end;

end;
```